# Есть ли плагины на WP с обратной связью в админку, а не на почтовики?

Tags: wordpress, форма, wordpress-плагины

Хочу поставить на сайте, сделанном на wordpress, форму заявки, но так, чтобы сообщения приходили не на почту, а в админку сайта. Самостоятельно найти такой плагин в интернете не удалось (все отправляют письма на почту). Существуют ли такие плагины?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, [Contact Form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) + [Flamingo](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/).

Answer (score 0):

К тому же [CF7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) есть несколько дополнений, которые это делают.